# How to correclty open a new window in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I want to read two elements from a web page, store their text in two variables and open a new window with an URL dependent of the variables' contents.

This is what my Selenese HTML looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>//dd[2]/strong</td>
    <td>str</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>//dd[3]/strong</td>
    <td>plz_ort</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${str} ${plz_ort}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>openWindow</td>
    <td>https://www.google.de/?q=${str}%20${plz_ort}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>name=btnG</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=lu_map</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I am using the `echo` to manually verify that the textual content of the elements has correctly been read. However, the Selenium IDE throws an error at the `openWindow` step:

> [warn] Opening window '_blank', which is not a real window name.
>   Randomizing target to be: selenium_blank19164
>   [error] Unexpected Exception: TypeError: result is null.

I have also tried to give the `openWindow` command a window name in the `Value` field (e.g. "random", "_blank", "foobar"), but this didn't work either.

The strange thing I wonder about: when I manually execute the command where the IDE fails it perfectly opens my window, even if still a warning is issued:

> [warn] Opening window '_blank', which is not a real window name. Randomizing target to be: selenium_blank23341

Debugging in the IDE shows that the error message also comes form the `openWindow` command.

I did not find related questions on SO. Any help how to further debug or fix this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I was using Firefox' [pop-up blocker](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pop-blocker-settings-exceptions-taroubleshooting#w_pop-up-blocker-settings) and did not pay attention to the original page. Adding the AUT to the exception list fixed the problem for me.